# PlayFramework 2.4 and IntelliJ 14

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to import a PlayFramework 2.4 project into IntelliJ 14.1.3. I failed to import existing one (created in pre-2.4), so made these steps:

1. Created a new play-java project via activator: `activator new appName`
2. Tried to open the created project via IntelliJ. (Opened the Open dialog, then selected the folder with my app, then set JDK to 1.8.0_45)

I'm getting this exception:

```
Error while importing SBT project: ... at 

scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34) at
scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244) at
scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105) at 
sbt.Classpaths$.appRepositories(Defaults.scala:1729) at 
sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$41.apply(Defaults.scala:1102) at 
sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$41.apply(Defaults.scala:1102) at 
scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47) at 
scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47) at 
sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175) at 
sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135) at 
sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:69) at 
sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:78) at 
sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:74) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [error] 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component [error] Use 
'last' for the full log. Invalid response. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0 See 
complete log in D:\.IntelliJIdea\system\log\sbt.last.log
```

sbt.last.log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.sbt$Classpaths$$bootRepository(Defaults.scala:1758)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1729)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1729)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.appRepositories(Defaults.scala:1729)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$41.apply(Defaults.scala:1102)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$41.apply(Defaults.scala:1102)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:69)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:78)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Invalid response.
```

Comment: Have you tried to import the project using  `New -> Project from Existing Sources...` so you can import it with SBT?

Comment: Yes. Same error occurs

Comment: Might be important: OS is Win7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to delete all .sbt, .ivy, .m2 folders in user home folder. Also I've removed SBT_HOME system variable. After that, IntelliJ was able to create valid project.

Comment: Just deleting the repositories file in the userhome/sbt directory will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

On windows just delete folder: C:\Users\.sbt
Check sbt command on your system is ok before launch intellij